# How do I add a href to an image in php on wordpress linking to another page?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am extremely new to coding and this is my first post here and I cannot figure this out for the life of me. I even had a friend who codes try but he also got stuck. The image uses a hover webkit transform to make the image a little bigger when hovered over. It does this in CSS:

```
.circle img {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0px auto 20px;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
    -moz-transform: scale(1,1);
    -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-transition-duration: 250ms;
}

circle:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05,1.07);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 250ms;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05,1.07);
    -moz-transition-timing-function:
}
```

The PHP:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="sixteen columns">
        <div class="five columns fma alpha">
            <div class="fma-content">
                <div class="circle">
                    <?php echo(types_render_field("home-fma-1-image", array())); ?>
                </div>
                <h3><?php echo(types_render_field("home-fma-1-headline", array())); ?></h3>
                <p><?php echo(types_render_field("home-fma-1-copy", array())); ?></p>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The image is the "home-fma-1-image" I think...

EDIT: I tried this:

```
<div class="circle">
<a href="whatever page"><?php echo(types_render_field("home-fma-1-image", array())); ?></a>
</div>
```

It made the whole thing a link, the image, the text below, and the other text below. This is a problem because my theme makes link text yellow and all caps which looks really weird for a paragraph.

Comment: so you are trying to make the image a clickable link?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the context, I'm assuming this is an image built into the theme? If so, it should be as easy as adding an a tag around the php code, and using a href attribute. See below:

```
<div class="circle">
    <a href="whatever page"><?php echo(types_render_field("home-fma-1-image", array())); ?></a>
</div>
```

Also, if you do this, change the css to incorporate the a tag.
`.circle a img`, rather than `.circle img`


Let me know if you're looking for something else, of course.